# How to get text from a textarea that does not have a `value` attribute?

Tags: java, selenium

How to get text from a textarea that does not have a `value` attribute?

```
<textarea name="comment_txt" class="comment_class"></textarea>
```

If it had a `value` attribute, I would go

```
driver.findElement(By.name("comment_txt")).getAttribute("value")
```

(ps: `getText` doesn't work)

Comment: But seems that your textarea doesn't contain any text and you tell that `getText doesn't work` - what result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still get the value by `getAttribute`, it will get the element's `value` property in that case.

This will change in the future with the w3c spec in that there will be a new method to get JUST the property. For now, however, if there is no attribute by that name it will attempt to get a property of that name.